# Find max negative and min positive numbers in a dataframe with negatives and positives

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to take the maximum negative value of a column containing negatives and positives (`diff_start`), and minimum positive value of another column (`diff_end`) in R.

**Data:**

```
data <- read.table(text ="
                   id lab diff_start diff_end
                   1 hb -1.7 -1.8
                   1 hb -0.3 -0.3
                   1 hb 0.6 0.5
                   1 hb 0.7 0.8", header = TRUE)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
# id lab   diff_start diff_end
# 1 hb     -0.3      0.5
```

What I have done:

- Split the data into 2, and filter `<= 0` for `diff_start` and `>= 0` for `diff_end`
- Obtain the summaries of interest, and then merge them back

I think this is pretty long and inefficient, and hope to make it more succinct.

```
full_join(
  data %>% 
    group_by(id, lab) %>% 
    filter(diff_start <= 0) %>% 
    summarise(diff_start = max(diff_start)) %>% 
    ungroup(),
  data %>% 
    group_by(id, lab) %>% 
    filter(diff_start >= 0) %>% 
    summarise(diff_end = min(diff_end)) %>% 
    ungroup())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can factorise your code this way:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, lab) %>% 
  summarise(diff_start = max(diff_start[diff_start <= 0]), diff_end = min(diff_end[diff_end >= 0])) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 1 x 4
     id lab   diff_start diff_end
  <int> <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 hb          -0.3      0.5
```

No need to filter first as you can do it in `summarize`.

To deal with missing negatives or positives:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, lab) %>% 
  summarise(
    diff_start = if(sum(diff_start <= 0) == 0) NA else max(diff_start[diff_start <= 0], na.omit = TRUE),
    diff_end = if(sum(diff_end >= 0) == 0) NA else min(diff_end[diff_end >= 0], na.omit = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Do you know how to revise this code if the dataframe has missing negative values for some of the `id` and `lab` combi, e.g. `data <- read.table(text ="
                   id lab diff_start diff_end
                   1 hb 0.6 0.5
                   1 hb 0.7 0.8", header = TRUE)`. Will be great if the code can output `NA` under `diff_start`.

Comment: @HNSKD Updated please have a look

Answer (score 4):

Give this a go:

```
max(data$diff_start[data$diff_start < 0]) 
min(data$diff_end[data$diff_end > 0])
```

Result:

```
> max(data$diff_start[data$diff_start < 0]) 
[1] -0.3
> min(data$diff_end[data$diff_end > 0])
[1] 0.5
```

Edit:

To maintain the grouping you can use:

```
by(data, list(data$id, data$lab), function(x) {
    c(max(x$diff_start[x$diff_start < 0]),
    min(x$diff_end[x$diff_end > 0]))
})
```

Output

```
[1] -0.3  0.5
```